# Save file list in a variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to create a variable string like below, for passing as an argument to a software.

```
"filename:file1.txt|file2.txt|file3.txt"
```

I know I need to use a FOR loop in this way

```
FOR %%i in (*.txt) DO
```

But I am not aware how to save the information in the same variable. I prefer, if it is possible not to pass the details in a external file.

Answer (score 1):

to append a string to a variable: `set var=%var%new`
You need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) to do this in a loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "list="
FOR %%i in (*.txt) DO set "list=!list!|%%i"
rem remove the first pipe symbol:
set list="%list:~1%"
echo %list%
```